# Pass around an "AppendOnlyStringBuilder"

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I have a serialization task where different parts and pieces of my object model know how to emit their own string segments, but I'd like the option to emit them using `.Append` against a common `StringBuilder` object. On the theory that we should not pass around our private objects for others to use indiscriminately, here's a class that wraps a `StringBuilder` to make it "append-only" for use in my scenario.

```
public sealed class AppendOnlyStringBuilder {
   private readonly StringBuilder _stringBuilder;

   public AppendOnlyStringBuilder(StringBuilder stringBuilder)
   {
      _stringBuilder = stringBuilder;
   }

   public AppendOnlyStringBuilder Append<T>(T value)
   {
      _stringBuilder.Append(value);
      return this;
   }
}
```

If my code inside of the different chunks of my model right now all look similar to this:

```
// Chunk1 class
public override string ToString() {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb
      .Append(_prop1.Value)
      .Append(_prop2.Value)
      .Append(_prop3.Value);
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

And these `ToString` methods are called from the main routine's serialization method like so:

```
// MainObject class
Chunk1 _chunk1;
Chunk2 _chunk2;
Chunk3 _chunk3;

public override string ToString() {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb
      .Append(_chunk1.ToString()) // ToString may be unnecessary here
      .Append(_chunk2.ToString())
      .Append(_chunk3.ToString());
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

How can I elegantly switch to passing around a single `AppendOnlyStringBuilder` for use in all these chunk classes instead of each one internally creating a new `StringBuilder` and doing `ToString`?

I'd like it to be used something like this:

```
// MainObject class
public override string ToString() {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   AppendOnlyStringBuilder aosb = new AppendOnlyStringBuilder(sb);
   aosb
      .Append(_chunk1)
      .Append(_chunk2)
      .Append(_chunk3);
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

An extension method is a natural way to get this syntax, but I'm running into problems due to the extension method needing to be static and thus not able to access private parts of the Chunk classes. I'd like to keep the same `ToString` in the chunk classes so they can still do their normal "serialize just me" thing, but I'd also like for them to be able to optionally append to my common `AppendOnlyStringBuilder`.

I guess I could do this:

```
_chunk1.AppendTo(aosb);
_chunk2.AppendTo(aosb);
_chunk3.AppendTo(aosb);
```

But something about that bugs me--I'd like to use a fluent interface that begins with the `AppendOnlyStringBuilder` object as in my example previously.

Comment: The various `Chunk` classes would have access only to an `AppendOnlyStringBuilder`. How could they do anything to the underlying object that the main object instantiated and kept private?

Comment: I would set up a system where objects serialize themselves to a TextWriter (but you can keep using StringBuilder if you prefer).  Then the ToString override simply creates a fresh TW (or SB), calls the other method, and returns the result.  The serialize method could be abstract and the ToString override defined only once in a base class.  This loses the method chaining, but I don't consider that a big loss. You might be able to preserve it with a visitor pattern.  I am not sure the effort would be worth it.

Comment: @phoog A `TextWriter` may be fine, as long as we don't end up with the problems of repeated string concatenation. Could you give some example code outlining your idea?

Comment: @ErikE working on it...

Comment: @phoog Something that writes directly to a stream (so it can be used to write to a file) would be awesome--eliminating the need to serialize in memory first...

Comment: #ErikE that's exactly why I would use a TextWriter -- it can be a StringWriter or a StreamWriter writing to a FileStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here goes:

```
using System.IO;

abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected abstract void WriteToTextWriter(TextWriter textWriter);

    public void SerializeTo(TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        WriteToTextWriter(textWriter);
    }

    public sealed override string ToString()
    {
        var writer = new StringWriter();
        SerializeTo(writer);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}

abstract class ChunkBase : BaseClass
{
    private readonly string _index;

    protected ChunkBase(string index)
    {
        _index = index;
    }

    protected sealed override void WriteToTextWriter(TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        textWriter.Write("Chunk");
        textWriter.Write(_index);
    }
}

class Chunk1 : ChunkBase { public Chunk1() : base("1") { } }
class Chunk2 : ChunkBase { public Chunk2() : base("2") { } }
class Chunk3 : ChunkBase { public Chunk3() : base("3") { } }

class ClassWithChunks : BaseClass
{
    private readonly Chunk1 _chunk1 = new Chunk1();
    private readonly Chunk2 _chunk2 = new Chunk2();
    private readonly Chunk3 _chunk3 = new Chunk3();

    protected override void WriteToTextWriter(TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        _chunk1.SerializeTo(textWriter);
        _chunk2.SerializeTo(textWriter);
        _chunk3.SerializeTo(textWriter);
    }
}
```

Now, if you want chaining, you could do this:

```
class Chainable
{
    private readonly TextWriter _textWriter;

    public Chainable(TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        _textWriter = textWriter;
    }

    public Chainable Write(BaseClass obj)
    {
        obj.SerializeTo(_textWriter);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then, your WriteToTextWriter could be, for example, this:

```
public override void WriteToTextWriter(TextWriter textWriter)
{
    new Chainable(textWriter)
        .Write(_chunk1)
        .Write(_chunk2)
        .Write(_chunk3);
}
```

I'm not sure it's worth it: the code is certainly cleaner, but it will be harder for someone (including your future self) to decipher, because of the additional layer of complexity.

Edit: Making the abstract method protected seems to add little here, but in production code, the extra layer could well be helpful.  You'll want to add some switches, too, to handle formatting and the like.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I guess I could have gotten to that myself. I was mostly stuck on wanting to somehow hide the `WriteToTextWriter` method from `public`.

Comment: @ErikE you can, of course.  I probably should have.  I made it public on the assumption that serializing to a file would require passing in a StreamWriter.  But of course, there ought to be a SerializeTo(StreamWriter) method or the like, which in turn calls WriteToTextWriter.  I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the ideal candidate for the adapter pattern.
(untested code)

```
public interface IAppendOnly
{
  void Append(string content);
}

public class AppendOnlyStringBuilder : IAppendOnly
{
  private StringBuilder _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder()

  public void Append(string content)
  {
    _stringBuilder.Append(content);
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return _stringBuilder.ToString();
  }
}

public class Chunk
{
  public void AppendTo(IAppendOnly appendOnly)
  {
    appendOnly.Append("My Content");
  }
}
```

Then each Chunk works without the knowledge of how the interface was instantiated:

```
_chunk1.AppendTo(aosb);
_chunk2.AppendTo(aosb);
_chunk3.AppendTo(aosb);
```

> But something about that bugs me--I'd like to use a fluent interface that begins with the AppendOnlyStringBuilder object as in my example previously.

So with this requirement (minus the unnecessary AppendOnlyStringBuilder class) you'd then switch the interface direction.

```
public interface IGetString
{
  string GetString();
}

public Chunk : IGetString
{
  public string GetString()
  {
    return "MyContent";
  }
}

public static class StringBuilderExtensions
{
  public static StringBuilder AppendFrom(this StringBuilder instance
    , IGetString getString)
  {
    instance.Append(getString.GetString())
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Then it's Fluent:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder;
var a = new Chunk();
var b = new Chunk();

sb.AppendFrom(a).AppendFrom(b);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion(s)! I will mull these options over.

Comment: It just depends on which direction makes more sense.  Since these appear to be abstract classes I can really tell which is the Principal and Dependant objects (although my gut tells me the bottom is closer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one instatiated object of a type you could use the singleton pattern (Google will give you many exampels)

If you have a global object (something like a "myApplication"-class) you could offer this there.

Other way is a static class offering this singleton instance "from everywhere".

Your code would append directly to this one instance...

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't help at all. I don't want a global singleton that each Chunk class independently has access to. Please re-read the question more carefully. The scope has to be **per serialization** not **per global application/execution**. There would be a terrible risk of reusing a previous, uncleared StringBuilder using the pattern you suggest.